# opening a html page on the client from server side

Tags: asp.net

On the server I receive xml from a webservice, I use xslt transformation on this xml to create a htm page. Now I need to show this htm page to the user by opening it in a new browser window. How do I achieve such functionality? My website is written in ASP.NET.

I have tried using

Response.Write("");
Response.Write("window.open('" + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/HTMLPage.htm")        + "','_blank')");
 Response.Write("");

But this throws me an access denied error.

Thanks in advance.

Chandrasekhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood it, you want this new page to open in a *new* browser window, correct?

If so, you're going about it the wrong way. Response.Redirect will only redirect the *current* page, not instantiate a new browser window.

What you need to do is inject a JavaScript command into the page that opens a new browser page. That command is **window.open**. Here's a quick way to do it:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newpage", "window.open('" + address +"');", true);
```

This code will insert the JavaScript command to execute when the page reloads after submission. Note that **address** is the string variable that contains the address of the page you want to open.

Another *very important* note: most browsers will consider this a pop-up window and may very well block it.